# Updating the build.grade to build a warfile and push it to artifactory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

My `build.gradle` has below changes to build a warfile and resolve dependencies from artifactory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '3.1.1')
        }
        configurations {
            warLib {
                transitive=false
            }
        }
    }

    war {
        classpath configurations.warLib
        classpath = classpath.files
    }

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = ‘aaa'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }

            defaults {
                publications('mavenJava')
                publishPom = false
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = ‘aba'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to build this code, I get an error:

> Cannot resolve external dependency abc:1.0.0 because no repositories are defined.

To fix the error, I added this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://localhost/artifactory/aba'
    }
}
```

*Note*

This means that the resolve option in artifactory is not resolving and I think it's because of the way I am building the war file. How can I fix it, so that I can build the war file and use the resolve option from artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to apply the `artifactory` plugin:

`apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"`

Comment: I have that applied too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10477624)

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi that's not a clarification from an author request, that's the answer. The build is failing because the author forgot to apply the plugin.

Comment: @Jason it's not in your build script.

Comment: @JBaruch, can this be an issue with the grade version that I am using, currently 2.6, because I do have the artifactory plugin applied.

Comment: @JBaruch. the below line in war was causing the issue: `classpath = classpath.files`.
Removing that builds the war.